# python (2/3) functions to use a USB-camera?

Tags: python, raspbian-stretch, image, webcam, video-input

After many attempts using pygame, or OpenCV to capture and display pictures from a standard USB-camera I decided to ask this question.

Mplayer worked with all cameras I have tested (a=Logitech, b=Creative, c=SPEEDLink). Mplayer works from commandline; I found no python adaptation.

The other libraries did not even recognize the camera or found a non existing format of the video stream.
Solutions from the internet describe older Raspbian OSs, maybe that's the problem. I am using 'Stretch' now and certainly will go on to 'Buster'.

so:

- can I use Mplayer from Python?

Other hints are welcome.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Raspbian Stretch is oldstable. If you start a new project you really should use the latest version Raspbian Buster.

Comment: @ingo: the question was closed with good reasons - so I worked it over, hoping it is ok now. Can you open it again, or do I have to put it as a new question?

Comment: @peets I still don't understand how you plan to use Mplayer to "capture and display pictures from python". It's a video player, not a webcam library. Could you concentrate on **what** you want to do, not on **how** you imagine doing it? Maybe you just need to look at a capture library, such as `pyv4l2`.

Comment: @peets I'm not a moderator so I cannot reopen it. I only can vote to reopen it (I've done) but you need 5 votes to reopen. Please note the comment from *@DmitryGrigoryev* above to improve your question.

Comment: @Dimitry, Ingo: Thanks for your help. My first attempt was describing the needs for my project but it was not well set to understand it. I'll try to follow the pyv4l2 hint.

Comment: @Dimitry: I want to mount a USB-camera on a CNC machine in place of the motor or laser head. The picture shall be displayed on a remote monitor using a RPi headless installation. A cross-hair points to a position of interest, e.g. a hole, a via, a pad on a PCB. Its coordinates shall be recorded pressing a key. While video capture worked well on my Ubuntu Linux a few years ago I ran into trouble using the RPi. Many examples from the Internet do not work. I am experienced in programming C/C++, a bit in Python now, and hardware in my well equipped lab. Inst. OpenCV drove me nuts -> post here

Comment: @Dimitry 2: Using 'mplayer' showed me, that the camera in question is working.

Comment: @Dimitry 2: Using 'mplayer' showed me, that the camera in question is working. I found another post somewhere who finally mentioned to use 'mplayer' for picture grabbing in a subprocess as a workaround. I have no experience in doing so. Of course I would prefer using a webcam library, especially OpenCV. To reduce my original question as requested by five members I tried this part. Helpful would be e.g. a short piece of working code on Buster (which is now installed). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: very helpful in finding cameras: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81776/86998